# Cloudformation AWS: Assign an ip address to a CustomerGateway using parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, ip-address, ipsec

I'm designing a cloudformation template, but I need to define the source IP as a Parameter

I tried to define the parameter as a String but it produces the following error:

```
Value (${MyCustomerGateway}) for parameter ipAddress is invalid. Invalid Format. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 4de02112-fb1f-47a1-931c-97727568df99)
```

this is the fragment of the template:

```
Parameters:
  MyCustomerGateway:
    Description: IpAddress.
    Default: 0.0.0.0
    Type: String  

Resources:
  CustomerGateway_1:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::CustomerGateway'
    Properties:
      Type: ipsec.1
      BgpAsn: 3352
      IpAddress: ${MyCustomerGateway} 
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: CustomerGateway_1
```

Is there any special data for the IP translation?

I'm not sure which is the right way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `IpAddress: ${MyCustomerGateway}`  to `IpAddress: !Ref myCustomerGateway`

More about [Ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) :

> The intrinsic function Ref returns the value of the specified
>   parameter or resource.
>
> **> When you specify a parameter's logical name, it returns the value of
>   the parameter.**
>
> When you specify a resource's logical name, it returns a value that
>   you can typically use to refer to that resource, such as a physical
>   ID.

**Bonus:**

In case you want to validate parameter inputs, you can use the [`AllowedPattern`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-regexes.html) property.

Usage:

```
PrimaryIPAddress:
    Type: String
    Description: This must be a valid IP address.
    AllowedPattern: (\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP address of the form x.x.x.x.
```

Error when entering invalid IP:

[image]